# Calling Data From GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, datagrid

I have a GridView with a bunch of DynamicFields like so;

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="GridDataSource">
<Columns>
<asp:DynamicField HeaderText="Date Submitted" DataField="DATE_CREATED" />
<asp:DynamicField HeaderText="Assigned To" DataField="ASSIGNED_TO" />
<asp:DynamicField HeaderText="Active Account" DataField="Active_Account" />
<asp:DynamicField HeaderText="Client ID" DataField="CLIENT_ID" />
<asp:DynamicField HeaderText="Client Type" DataField="CLIENT_Type" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="GridDataSource" OnSelected="TotalRows" runat="server" 
EnableDelete="true">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:DynamicControlParameter ControlID="FilterRepeater" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Now it displays fine, the right data comes to screen but when I try to access that data using a row number I'm always finding blank cells. For example I tried the following to check every cell but to no avail;

```
Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 0
    While x < GridView1.Rows.Count
        While y < GridView1.Rows(x).Cells.Count
            If Not (GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Text = "") Then
                MsgBox(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", x.ToString, y.ToString, 
                      GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Text))
            End If
            y = y + 1
        End While
        x = x + 1
        y = 0
    End While
```

No message box displayed so all the cells are empty strings. But I can clearly see they're populated on screen! What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After Pilgerstorfer Franz suggestion that I look for Textbox elements I used the following code which basically looks at all the cells in the table and try's to pull data out of them and if it's not blank then display a msgbox (also informs me of any new controls I haven't accounted for);

```
If GridView1.Rows(0).RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    For r = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For c = 0 To (GridView1.Rows(r).Cells.Count - 1)
            Dim cell = GridView1.Rows(r).Cells(c)

            For b = 0 To cell.Controls.Count - 1
                If (cell.Controls(b).GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
                    Dim td = CType(cell.Controls(b), TextBox)
                    Text = td.Text.Trim
                ElseIf (cell.Controls(b).GetType() Is GetType(LiteralControl)) Then
                    Dim td = CType(cell.Controls(b), LiteralControl)
                    Text = td.Text.Trim
                ElseIf (cell.Controls(b).GetType() Is GetType(DynamicControl)) Then
                    Dim td = CType(cell.Controls(b), DynamicControl)
                    Text = td.Table.Columns.Item(c).DisplayName()
                Else
                    MsgBox(String.Format("New Control of type: {0}", cell.Controls(b).GetType().FullName))
                End If
                If Not Text = "" Then
                    MsgBox(String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", c.ToString, b.ToString, Text))
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End If
```

Unfortunately most cells just contained DynamicControl and since I was putting the `DisplayName` into `Text` I was just getting the column header every time. So how do I get the text value property out of a DynamicControl?

**Additional Info**

I'm further confused by this problem because since this is a project that I'm updating there is initial code two lines of which are;

```
Dim UserID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)
Dim clientType As String = GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Item(1).ToString
```

These successfully bring back UserID and ClientType. Now I don't really understand DataKeys but I tried using;

```
Dim clientType As String = GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Item(Num).ToString
```

where `Num` increases by one every time expecting it to bring back the rest of the row data, but I simply got an index was out of range error.

**ANOTHER UPDATE!!**

Here is another bit of the ASPX page but I'n not entirely certain what it does. Pilgerstorfer Franz created some code to look for the textboxes created by the dynamicControl. Now I'm wondering if this code here causes other types of controls to be used rather than Textboxes. Thoughts?

```
<asp:FilterRepeater ID="FilterRepeater" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h2><asp:Label ID="lblDisplay" runat="server" Text='<%#
Eval("DisplayName") %>' AssociatedControlID="DynamicFilter$DropDownList1" /></h2>
                <asp:DynamicFilter runat="server" ID="DynamicFilter" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnFilterSelectedIndexChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate><br /><br /></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:FilterRepeater>
```

Comment: Note: using a Msgbox in ASP.NET does not make any sense (and won't work on a machine other than the server). You should be using a Javascript Alert for this: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "AlertMessageBox", "alert('oops');", True)`

Comment: What event do you use for your code? (page_load, Button_click ...)

Comment: `Protected Sub GridView1_Updating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating` is my method stub which comes from a `LinkButton`

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz You thinking my gridview could actually be empty when the event is running due to a postback or something?

Comment: When updating there may be textboxes in your cells. I didn't check it, but you may try accessing the control(s) within your cells (something like: Dim t as Textbox = GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Controls(0) as Textbox)

Comment: I was wondering if that was a possibility. Will give it a go and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through the controls never worked for me so in the end I gave up and just queried the DB again... Eh it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to my assumptions (see comments) I did a small demo...

```
<asp:DynamicDataManager ID="DynamicDataManager1" runat="server">
        <DataControls>
            <asp:DataControlReference ControlID="GridView1" />
        </DataControls>
</asp:DynamicDataManager>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      DataKeyNames="ContactID" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" AllowPaging="true" 
       OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>                
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="ContactID" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="ContactID" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
            <asp:DynamicField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=dbTestIT34_EFEntities"
        DefaultContainerName="dbTestIT34_EFEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EnableUpdate="True"
        EntitySetName="Contacts" EntityTypeFilter="Contact">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

And according to my data storage I did handle the rowUpdating event. Unfortunatelly accessing any control within a dynamic control is not easy. So I did a very quick and dirty hack...

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EnableDynamicData(typeof(Contact));
    EntityDataSource1.ContextType = typeof(dbTestIT34_EFEntities);
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int row = 0;
    int firstNameColumn = 2;
    while (row < GridView1.Rows.Count)
    {
        // sorry, a little bit confusing ...
        //     as dynamic control generates other controls dynamically, 
        //     this was the very first thing that worked for me!
        TextBox t = GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[firstNameColumn].Controls[0].Controls[0].Controls[0] as TextBox;
        if (t != null)
            Debug.WriteLine(t.Text);

        row++;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I rewrote your code in VB like so   `Dim row As Integer = 0  
        Dim firstNameColumn As Integer = 2  
        Dim t As TextBox  
        While (row < GridView1.Rows.Count)  
            t = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(row).Cells(firstNameColumn).Controls(0).Controls(0).Controls(0), TextBox)  
            If Not t Is Nothing Then  
                MsgBox(t.Text)  
            End If  
  
            row = row + 1  
        End While`

Comment: But unfortunately it didn't come across any textboxes with text in them. Can understand why it's so difficult just to read a grid :/